# Why would the Death Eaters want to blow their cover?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

After Voldemort's fall in the first wizarding war, most death eaters were rounded off and sent to Azkaban. But few of them were able to fool the ministry that they were under imperius curse and they were never Voldemort's supporters.

My question is, what triggered them to march during the Quidditch world cup in front of the whole ministry? They clearly weren't aware of Voldemort's plan of regaining his body. How come they decided to stop fearing going to Azkaban after 13 years at a place where they were bound to be caught by officials.

Answer (score 6):

#### Most likely, it was a form of drunken revelry.

Harry asks Arthur Weasley a similar question about why the Death Eaters chose to levitate Muggles, and he responded that they probably had some drinks and wanted to remind the wizarding world they were still out there.

> “What were You-Know-Who’s supporters up to, levitating Muggles? I mean, what was the point?’
>
> ‘The point?’ said Mr Weasley, with a hollow laugh. ‘Harry, that’s their idea of fun. Half the Muggle killings back when You-Know-Who was in power were done for fun. I suppose they had a few drinks tonight and couldn’t resist reminding us all that lots of them are still at large. A nice little reunion for them,’ he finished disgustedly.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9 (The Dark Mark)*</sup></sub>

So it was likely something they chose to do while drunk, and not at the height of their reasoning abilities. However, even though it was not the most logical place for the Death Eaters to strike, they could still Disapparate before Ministry wizards caught them - and that’s exactly what they did.

> “They all Disapparated before we’d got near enough to unmask any of them.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9 (The Dark Mark)*</sup></sub>

It was certainly a risky decision, but they did have and use the ability to Disapparate before they were caught.